# External page transition not working - "data-ajax=false"

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app in iOS using jQuery Mobile v1.3.1

The problem is next page loads very slow and transition is not visible due to external page loading.

Then how can I show transition in external page loading while `data-ajax` is disabled?

Comment: This is a known issue.can you show the code you have tried...jquery mobile works on ajax page requets hence data-ajax="true" may help to continue with transitions.

Comment: <a href="browse.html" data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide">

Comment: so, how can I show transition when have writen data-ajax="false" ?

Comment: first of all even jquery mobile latest version is not yet very smooth with page transitions.so either we have to turn them off or use them with ajax page request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@NJInamadar` said

This is a known issue.can you show the code you have tried...`jquery mobile` works on ajax page requets hence `data-ajax="true"` may help to continue with transitions. – NJInamdar 39 mins ago

you have to use

```
<a href="browse.html" data-ajax="true" data-transition="slide">
```

then only transition will work

Comment: But i want full page reload using data-ajax=false , since I want to load different .js and .css for different pages.

Comment: In this case use `data-rel=external` or add your CSS and js in body not in head @user2447014

Comment: When I add data-rel="external" transition is not visible , and page loading takes much time.

Comment: my log says:log:                                                2013-06-28 12:19:34.196 Tax India[37509:c07] Resetting plugins due to page load. 2013-06-28 12:19:34.314 Tax India[37509:c07] Finished load of: file:///Users/volansys/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/83632DFD-529B-4733-9342-2F65F202CB8C/Tax%20India.app/www/s_chart_14_b1.html 2013-06-28 12:42:38.233 Tax India[37816:c07] DEPRECATION NOTICE: The Connection ReachableViaWWAN return value of '2g' is deprecated as of Cordova version 2.6.0 and will be changed to 'cellular' in a future release.

Comment: @user2447014 then keep ajax true (true by default) and add css/js inside body.

Comment: @Omar what if my jquery page is multipage templete? So here where should I include all .js and .css inside body ? please give some example.

Comment: @user2447014 read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923600/when-to-use-a-multi-page-document-vs-multiple-pages-in-jquery-mobile) first to decide whether to go for single-page or multi-page. I'll give you and answer based on your decision.

Comment: my requirement is : currently I am single-page. And I link new page with data-ajax="false" , this page is multi-page. So in this second page if I call it via data-ajax="true" , where should I place js and css inside body? And similary when I go back to 1st single-page where should I place js and css?